# Setting focus on postback initiated by javascript

Tags: asp.net, javascript

I am working with ASP.NET doing some client side javascript.
I have the following javascript to handle an XMLHTTPRequest callback.  In certain situations, the page will be posted back, using the __doPostBack() function provided by ASP.NET, listed in the code below.  However, I would like to be able to set the focus a dropdownlist controls after the post back occurs.  Is there a way to set this using Javascript, or do I need to rig that up some other way.

```
    function onCompanyIDSuccess(sender, e) {
       if (sender == 0)
           document.getElementById(txtCompanyIDTextBox).value = "";
       document.getElementById(txtCompanyIDHiddenField).value = sender;
       if (bAutoPostBack) {
           __doPostBack(txtCompanyIDTextBox, '');
       }
   }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have found the solution for this one.  In the code behind event handler being called for each particular item, I call the Control.Focus() as the last line.  For instance, if a dropdownlist event handler is being triggered, and the next control to get focused is the zipcode text box:

```
protected void ddl_state_selectedValueChanged(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // ... here is all my code for the event handler

    txtZipCode.Focus();
}
```

It was much easier that I what I was trying to do.  I keep trying to overcomplicate things by creating Javascript on the fly that does exactly what Microsoft is already doing for me in the Framework.

Answer (score 3):

Since you're doing a full postback, you'd need to use [Page.SetFocus](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e04ah0f4.aspx) on the server side to get the appropriate JavaScript emitted on the next page load.

Otherwise, in a pure AJAX solution - document.getElementById('id').focus() would do the trick.

Comment: +1. You prove what makes SO such a fantastic resource on the web.